# "No signature of method" for the groovy readYaml method in Jenkins Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, yaml, devops

I'm trying to build a bunch of similar jobs (changing parameters) by reading from a config YAML file.

However, when I try to use the readYaml method from the pipeline-utility-steps-plugin (version 2.5.0 is installed) I get the following error when I try to seed it:

```
ERROR: (borg_backups.groovy, line 31) No signature of method: borg_backups.readYaml() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[file:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/seed-job/redacted/us-west-2/borg-backups/config/borg-stage-config.yml]]
Finished: FAILURE
```

This is the snippet of the code where I use it:

```
environments.each { envEntry ->
    folder("$basePath/$envEntry.key") {
        displayName("$envEntry.value")
        description("Backup Jobs uploaded to Borg $envEntry.value environment")
    }

    regions.each { regionEntry ->
        String configFilePath = "redacted/$regionEntry/borg-backups/config/borg-$envEntry.key-config.yml"
        def fullTestPath = new File("$seedWorkspacePath/$configFilePath")
        if( fullTestPath.exists() ) {
            folder("$basePath/$envEntry.key/$regionEntry") {
                displayName("$regionEntry")
                description("Backup Jobs uploaded to Borg $envEntry.value environment: $regionEntry region")
            }

            def configs = readYaml (file: "$seedWorkspacePath/$configFilePath")
            if (configs.borg_environment == "stage"){
                folder("$basePath/$envEntry.key/$regionEntry/kafka") {
                    displayName(configs.services.kafka.name)
                    description("Checking if it is parsing the YAML configs correctly")
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is this within the `Jenkinsfile` or an external class/method?

Comment: @MattSchuchard it is is a groovy file that is loaded by the seed.groovy file: "Processing DSL script jenkins-jobs/borg/borg_backups.groovy"

Comment: We're also using https://plugins.jenkins.io/script-security/ so I might need to add the script signature to the approved ones, but I'm not sure what its signature is...